# Sharepoint 2016 Configuration wizard error timeout

Tags: 2016, configuration

Hope someone can help me! I have two servers one for SharePoint 2016 with custom roles and the other SQL 2014.

Two days ago There was a problem with my search service. so I delete it completely from my farm. Service, Pool and search databases.

Now when I try to create the service again from central admin configuration wizard, it keep processing for about an hour and then gave me an error something went wrong request time out! tried to create it from PowerShell! still no success!

For troubleshooting I deleted access service and tried to recreate it back by the same steps. it gave me the same error!

**Colleration ID error**

```
07/08/2017 21:10:59.39  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Flighting Infrastructure    asodk   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 07/08/2017 21:10:59.37, Original Level: Verbose] Got feature toggle. FeatureID: '{0}', Toggle: '{1}'   985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:10:59.39  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] Entering Monitored Scope ({0}). Parent={1} 985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:00.67  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Flighting Infrastructure    asodk   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 07/08/2017 21:10:59.39, Original Level: Verbose] Got feature toggle. FeatureID: '{0}', Toggle: '{1}'   985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:00.67  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Flighting Infrastructure    bht46   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] {0} Evaluating flight for ring {1} 985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:02.04  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Flighting Infrastructure    asodk   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 07/08/2017 21:11:00.67, Original Level: Verbose] Got feature toggle. FeatureID: '{0}', Toggle: '{1}'   985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:02.04  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Flighting Infrastructure    bht46   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] {0} Evaluating flight for ring {1} 985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:03.22  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Flighting Infrastructure    asodk   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 07/08/2017 21:11:02.06, Original Level: Verbose] Got feature toggle. FeatureID: '{0}', Toggle: '{1}'   985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:03.22  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Flighting Infrastructure    bht46   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] {0} Evaluating flight for ring {1} 985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:04.36  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Flighting Infrastructure    asodk   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 07/08/2017 21:11:03.23, Original Level: Verbose] Got feature toggle. FeatureID: '{0}', Toggle: '{1}'   985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:04.36  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Flighting Infrastructure    bht46   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] {0} Evaluating flight for ring {1} 985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:04.43  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Flighting Infrastructure    asodk   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 07/08/2017 21:11:04.39, Original Level: Verbose] Got feature toggle. FeatureID: '{0}', Toggle: '{1}'   985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:04.43  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Flighting Infrastructure    bht46   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] {0} Evaluating flight for ring {1} 985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:05.60  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Flighting Infrastructure    asodk   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 07/08/2017 21:11:04.43, Original Level: Verbose] Got feature toggle. FeatureID: '{0}', Toggle: '{1}'   985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:05.60  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Flighting Infrastructure    bht46   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] {0} Evaluating flight for ring {1} 985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:05.72  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   General a01g1   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 07/08/2017 21:11:05.64, Original Level: VerboseEx] Calling SPContext.Current   985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:05.72  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   General a01g1   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: VerboseEx] Calling SPContext.Current    985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:05.91  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   General a01g1   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 07/08/2017 21:11:05.74, Original Level: VerboseEx] Calling SPContext.Current   985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:05.91  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Database    8acb    High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: VerboseEx] Reverting to process identity    985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:05.97  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Database    asutt   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 07/08/2017 21:11:05.91, Original Level: Verbose] Query Duration: query {0}, connection {1} for procedure {2} in database {3} on server {4} 985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:05.97  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   General a01g1   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: VerboseEx] Calling SPContext.Current    985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:06.05  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Database    ahjqp   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 07/08/2017 21:11:06.00, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 26.792354250527 for Data Source=TIP-SP-DB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Application Name=SqlSession[w3wp][2][master] ConnectionId: a6a4ca71-43ec-47c7-bdb0-7811730ef414  985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:06.05  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Database    asutt   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] Query Duration: query {0}, connection {1} for procedure {2} in database {3} on server {4}  985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:06.05  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Config DB   azcxo   High    SPPersistedObjectCollectionCache: Missed memory and file cache, falling back to SQL query. CollectionType=Dependency, ObjectType=Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceInstance, CollectionParentId=f3dad1c3-3160-46a1-8963-0325d645b323, Object Count=1, Stack=   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObjectCollectionCache.Get[T](SPPersistedObjectCollection`1 collection)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPPersistedStoreProvider.GetBackingList[U](SPPersistedObjectCollection`1 persistedCollection)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObjectCollection`1.get_BackingList()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObjectCollection`1.<GetEnumeratorImpl>d__0.MoveNext()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.get_IsContentWebServiceRunning()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ExtendVirtualServerPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:08.35  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   General a01g1   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 07/08/2017 21:11:06.07, Original Level: VerboseEx] Calling SPContext.Current   985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:08.35  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Config Cache    az66h   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] SPPersistedObjectCollectionCache.Get: object type={0}, collection={1}  985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:09.08  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Config Cache    az66i   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 07/08/2017 21:11:08.35, Original Level: Verbose] SPPersistedObjectCollectionCache.Get: memory cache hit. objectIDs count={0}   985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:09.08  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   General f6l7    High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] Entering Monitored Scope ({0}). Parent={1} 985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:10.11  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Config Cache    az66h   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] SPPersistedObjectCollectionCache.Get: object type={0}, collection={1}  985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:12.15  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Config Cache    az66i   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 07/08/2017 21:11:10.11, Original Level: Verbose] SPPersistedObjectCollectionCache.Get: memory cache hit. objectIDs count={0}   985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:12.15  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Config Cache    az66h   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] SPPersistedObjectCollectionCache.Get: object type={0}, collection={1}  985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:15.50  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   General a01g1   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 07/08/2017 21:11:12.15, Original Level: VerboseEx] Calling SPContext.Current   985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:15.50  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   Config Cache    az66h   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] SPPersistedObjectCollectionCache.Get: object type={0}, collection={1}  985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
07/08/2017 21:11:15.56  w3wp.exe (0x664C)   0x7F14  SharePoint Foundation   General agxkz   High    calling GetCurrentGenericSetupPath for a versioned path: TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS   985c039e-2ff0-20ed-b794-353db7f016ac
```

Comment: Please improve your question a little: Add the lines of PowerShell you used for creating Search. Your ULS-Log contains no useful information. Try to find an error with level "Unexpected" or "Critical" and post all messages with same Correlation-ID

Comment: You may refer the below answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/213006/timeout-issues-when-provisioning-service-applications-sharepoint-2016/268709#268709